# How to login in MySQL with a Non Root user

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I have setup 2 user `Uone` and `Utwo` in Mysql. But when I open `localhost/phpmyadmin` it logins with root user. What URL is used to login with `Uone` or `Utwo` user. I am running Mysql from XAMPP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you had installed phpmyadmin separately, you would be asked for username and password in the startup.

Since you have a pre-installed version of phpmyadmin. You can do the following to do so.

1. Find the `phpmyadmin` installation or project file
2. Open the file called `config.inc.php`
3. Inside you will find details to change the username and password `...`

   ```
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'Uone';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'cbb74bc'; // use here your password
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Under XAMPP (I haven't used it), can you log out of phpmyadmin while logged in as root, then log back in as the other user? That's one usual way :-)

Comment: You're not the only one (Google 'phpmyadmin logout')! Depends on the version, on some, it's on the home page as 'EXIT' with an arrow pointing to the right... YMMV